How to decrease the computation timing while using NIntegrate?
I'm trying to calculate the $A$ and $F$ values by using this code,
       AA[z_, B_] = -a z^2 - d B^2 z^5;
    
    G1dd[zh_, 
       B_] = {{-((E^(2 AA[z, B]) L^2 g[z, zh, B])/z^2), 0, 0, 0, 
        0}, {0, (E^(2 AA[z, B]) L^2)/(z^2 g[z, zh, B]), 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
        0, (E^(2 AA[z, B]) L^2)/z^2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
        0, (E^(B^2 z^2 + 2 AA[z, B]) L^2)/z^2, 2 B π αp}, {0, 
        0, 0, -2 B π αp, (E^(B^2 z^2 + 2 AA[z, B]) L^2)/z^2}};
    G1uu[zh_, 
       B_] = {{-((E^(-2 AA[z, B]) z^2)/(L^2 g[z, zh, B])), 0, 0, 0, 
        0}, {0, (E^(-2 AA[z, B]) z^2 g[z, zh, B])/L^2, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
        0, (E^(-2 AA[z, B]) z^2)/L^2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
        0, (E^(B^2 z^2 + 
              2 AA[z, B]) L^2 z^2)/(E^(2 B^2 z^2 + 4 AA[z, B]) L^4 + 
           4 B^2 π^2 z^4 αp^2), -((2 B π z^4 \
    αp)/(E^(2 B^2 z^2 + 4 AA[z, B]) L^4 + 
             4 B^2 π^2 z^4 αp^2))}, {0, 0, 
        0, (2 B π z^4 αp)/(E^(2 B^2 z^2 + 4 AA[z, B]) L^4 + 
           4 B^2 π^2 z^4 αp^2), (E^(B^2 z^2 + 
              2 AA[z, B]) L^2 z^2)/(E^(2 B^2 z^2 + 4 AA[z, B]) L^4 + 
           4 B^2 π^2 z^4 αp^2)}};
    g[z_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ, B_?NumericQ] := 
     1 - NIntegrate[ζ^3 Exp[-B^2 ζ^2 - 
           3 AA[ζ, B]], {ζ, 0, z}]/
       NIntegrate[ζ^3 Exp[-B^2 ζ^2 - 
           3 AA[ζ, B]], {ζ, 0, zh}]
    Temp[zh_?NumericQ, 
      B_?NumericQ] := (E^(-B^2 zh^2 - 
           3 AA[zh, B]) zh^3)/(4 π NIntegrate[
         E^(-B^2 ζ^2 - 3 AA[ζ, B]) ζ^3, {ζ, 0, 
          zh}])
    
    ff[zh_, B_] = -(1/z^2) 2 E^(2 (B^2 z^2 + AA[z, B])) L^2 Sqrt[
        1 + (B^2 E^(-2 B^2 z^2 - 4 AA[z, B]) z^4)/(bb^2 L^4)] (g[z, zh, 
           B] (-2 + 2 B^2 z^2 + 3 z D[AA[z, B], z]) + z D[g[z, zh, B], z]);
    term[z_, zh_, B_] = 
      Sqrt[-Det[G1dd[zh, B]]] G1uu[zh, B][[2, 2]] G1uu[zh, B][[3, 3]] ff[
        zh, B];
    αvalue[zh_, B_, ω_] = (I ω)/(4 π Temp[zh, B]);
    ϵ = 0.0001; L = 1; ls = 2.702; αp = ls^2; bb = 
     1/(2 π αp); a = 0.15; d = 0.013;
    zhBpt2 = 1.342;
    sol[zh_, B_, ω_] := 
     NDSolve[{f''[z] + 
         D[Log[term[z, zhBpt2, 0.2]], z] f'[
           z] - ω^2 ((G1uu[zhBpt2, 0.2][[1, 1]]/
             G1uu[zhBpt2, 0.2][[2, 2]])) f[z] == 0, 
       f[ϵ] == 
        1 + ω^2/
          2 ϵ^2 - (1/2 0.2^2 ω^2 + ω^4/
            16) Log[ϵ] ϵ^4, 
       f'[ϵ] == ω^2/
          2 ϵ - (1/2 0.2^2 ω^2 + ω^4/
            16) ϵ^3 - (2 0.2^2 ω^2 + ω^4/
            4) Log[ϵ] ϵ^3}, 
      f, {z, ϵ, zhBpt2 - ϵ}]
    v1[zh_, B_, ω_] := 
     Part[Simplify[(A + 
             I F) (1 - (zhBpt2 - 0.0001)/zhBpt2)^-αvalue[zhBpt2, 
              0.2, ω] + (A - 
             I F) (1 - (zhBpt2 - 0.0001)/zhBpt2)^αvalue[zhBpt2, 
             0.2, ω] == Evaluate[f[zhBpt2 - 0.0001]] /. 
        sol[zh, B, ω]], 1]
    v2[zh_, B_, ω_] := 
     Part[Simplify[(A + 
             I F) (1 - (zhBpt2 - 0.0002)/zhBpt2)^-αvalue[zhBpt2, 
              0.2, ω] + (A - 
             I F) (1 - (zhBpt2 - 0.0002)/zhBpt2)^αvalue[zhBpt2, 
             0.2, ω] == Evaluate[f[zhBpt2 - 0.0002]] /. 
        sol[zh, B, ω]], 1]
    s[zh_, B_, ω_] := {A, F} /. 
      Solve[v1[zh, B, ω] && v2[zh, B, ω], {A, F}]
    AnFvalues = 
     Flatten[Table[s[zhBpt2, 0.2, ω], {ω, 0.01, 3, 0.01}], 
      1]

It has been running for the last 5 hours without any result till now.
In the code, when I defined AA[z] as,
 AA[z_] = -a z^2;

and used Integrate in place of NIntegrate in g[z, zh, B] and in Temp[zh, B] as shown in the code below,
        AA[z_] = -a z^2;
    
    G1dd[zh_, 
       B_] = {{-((E^(2 AA[z]) L^2 g[z, zh, B])/z^2), 0, 0, 0, 
        0}, {0, (E^(2 AA[z]) L^2)/(z^2 g[z, zh, B]), 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
        0, (E^(2 AA[z]) L^2)/z^2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
        0, (E^(B^2 z^2 + 2 AA[z]) L^2)/z^2, 2 B π αp}, {0, 0, 
        0, -2 B π αp, (E^(B^2 z^2 + 2 AA[z]) L^2)/z^2}};
    G1uu[zh_, 
       B_] = {{-((E^(-2 AA[z]) z^2)/(L^2 g[z, zh, B])), 0, 0, 0, 
        0}, {0, (E^(-2 AA[z]) z^2 g[z, zh, B])/L^2, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
        0, (E^(-2 AA[z]) z^2)/L^2, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
        0, (E^(B^2 z^2 + 2 AA[z]) L^2 z^2)/(E^(2 B^2 z^2 + 4 AA[z]) L^4 + 
           4 B^2 π^2 z^4 αp^2), -((2 B π z^4 \
    αp)/(E^(2 B^2 z^2 + 4 AA[z]) L^4 + 
             4 B^2 π^2 z^4 αp^2))}, {0, 0, 
        0, (2 B π z^4 αp)/(E^(2 B^2 z^2 + 4 AA[z]) L^4 + 
           4 B^2 π^2 z^4 αp^2), (E^(B^2 z^2 + 
              2 AA[z]) L^2 z^2)/(E^(2 B^2 z^2 + 4 AA[z]) L^4 + 
           4 B^2 π^2 z^4 αp^2)}};
    
    g[z_, zh_, B_] := 
     1 - Integrate[ζ^3 Exp[-B^2 ζ^2 - 
           3 AA[ζ]], {ζ, 0, z}]/
       Integrate[ζ^3 Exp[-B^2 ζ^2 - 3 AA[ζ]], {ζ, 
         0, zh}]
    
    Temp[zh_, 
      B_] := (E^(-B^2 zh^2 - 3 AA[zh]) zh^3)/(4 π Integrate[
         E^(-B^2 ζ^2 - 3 AA[ζ]) ζ^3, {ζ, 0, zh}])
    
    
    ff[zh_, B_] = -(1/z^2) 2 E^(2 (B^2 z^2 + AA[z])) L^2 Sqrt[
        1 + (B^2 E^(-2 B^2 z^2 - 4 AA[z]) z^4)/(bb^2 L^4)] (g[z, zh, 
           B] (-2 + 2 B^2 z^2 + 3 z D[AA[z], z]) + z D[g[z, zh, B], z]);
    
    term[z_, zh_, B_] = 
      Sqrt[-Det[G1dd[zh, B]]] G1uu[zh, B][[2, 2]] G1uu[zh, B][[3, 3]] ff[
        zh, B];
    
    αvalue[zh_, B_, ω_] = (I ω)/(4 π Temp[zh, B]);
    
    ϵ = 0.0001; L = 1; ls = 2.702; αp = ls^2; bb = 
     1/(2 π αp); a = 0.15; d = 0.013;
    zhBpt2 = 1.342;
    
    sol[zh_, B_, ω_] := 
     NDSolve[{f''[z] + 
         D[Log[term[z, zhBpt2, 0.2]], z] f'[
           z] - ω^2 ((G1uu[zhBpt2, 0.2][[1, 1]]/
             G1uu[zhBpt2, 0.2][[2, 2]])) f[z] == 0, 
       f[ϵ] == 
        1 + ω^2/
          2 ϵ^2 - (1/2 0.2^2 ω^2 + ω^4/
            16) Log[ϵ] ϵ^4, 
       f'[ϵ] == ω^2/
          2 ϵ - (1/2 0.2^2 ω^2 + ω^4/
            16) ϵ^3 - (2 0.2^2 ω^2 + ω^4/
            4) Log[ϵ] ϵ^3}, 
      f, {z, ϵ, zhBpt2 - ϵ}]
    
    v1[zh_, B_, ω_] := 
     Part[Simplify[(A + 
             I F) (1 - (zhBpt2 - 0.0001)/zhBpt2)^-αvalue[zhBpt2, 
              0.2, ω] + (A - 
             I F) (1 - (zhBpt2 - 0.0001)/zhBpt2)^αvalue[zhBpt2, 
             0.2, ω] == Evaluate[f[zhBpt2 - 0.0001]] /. 
        sol[zh, B, ω]], 1]
    
    v2[zh_, B_, ω_] := 
     Part[Simplify[(A + 
             I F) (1 - (zhBpt2 - 0.0002)/zhBpt2)^-αvalue[zhBpt2, 
              0.2, ω] + (A - 
             I F) (1 - (zhBpt2 - 0.0002)/zhBpt2)^αvalue[zhBpt2, 
             0.2, ω] == Evaluate[f[zhBpt2 - 0.0002]] /. 
        sol[zh, B, ω]], 1]
    
    s[zh_, B_, ω_] := {A, F} /. 
      Solve[v1[zh, B, ω] && v2[zh, B, ω], {A, F}]
    
    AnFvalues = 
     Flatten[Table[s[zhBpt2, 0, ω], {ω, 0.01, 3, 0.01}], 1]

it took around 30 seconds to compute the values, but with the present form of AA[z] as,
AA[z_, B_] = -a z^2 - d B^2 z^5;

and using NIntegrate, it keeps running.
Can anyone explain why it takes so much computation time and how to overcome this?

Why do you want to use NIntegerate if Integrate works?

When I'm using the second AA[z] i.e. $- a z^2 -d B^2 z^5$, Integrate is not working for finite values of $B$, that's why I'm using NIntegrate. For first AA[z] Integrate is working for finite  $B$.

Please see the edited codes

If you make the all dependencies explicit, for example g[a_?NumericQ, d_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ, B_?NumericQ] := ..., then it becomes easier to test the code step-by-step and find out where the bottleneck is, and start optimizing the steps. As it is, your code is too messy to analyze.

Derivatives like D[g[z, zh, B], z] should probably be defined as separate functions: dgdz[a_?NumericQ, d_?NumericQ, z_?NumericQ, zh_?NumericQ, B_?NumericQ] := ... with an explicit formulation of the derivative (remember the fundamental theorem of calculus).

I've tried it by using your approach, but sadly it's not working.
